# Given a positive number , how to determine its surrounding integers in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, if-statement

Can someone please explain how to get the surrounding integers for a given positive number ( for ex. if number is 18.2378 then it should return 18 and 19 )

(I actually need this to determine that the given number is between 0-1 or 2-3 or 4-5 and so on....and if it is in between 0-1 or 2-3 or 4-5 etc then some expression evaluates , else some other expression must evaluate.)

Comment: What if it's between 1-2 or 3-4. What do you want to happen then?

Comment: Use `if mod(x,2)<1 expression1 else expression2 end`?

Answer (score 2):

The `floor` and `ceil` functions do this:

```
x = 18.2378;
floor(x);  %Returns 18
ceil(x);   %Returns 19
```

Answer (score 1):

`floor(18.2378)` will return **18** i.e. the previous nearest integer.

`ceil(18.2378)` will return **19** i.e. the next nearest integer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `round` or `floor` or `ceil` in Matlab to turn decimal numbers into integers. Round will round up or down depending on the decimal value, floor rounds toward minus infinity, and ceil rounds toward positive infinity.

Here is an example of how this could work:

```
n=18.2378;
F=floor(n);
C=ceil(n);
TF=F<n<C;
```

F returns 18. C returns 19. TF will return 1 if the number is between the floor and the ceiling--**But, if you do it this way the number will always be between its floor and ceiling**--and 0 if it is not. You can do this iteratively in a loop as many times as you need.